# How do I detect when an item is added to a ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I've looked all over and can find nothing. The only solution I've found is to manually call the function when you add an item, but that's inefficient, and I know it's possible.

Comment: Is this ASP, winform, WPF, silverlight, or what?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: Are you using Winforms or WPF

Comment: Could you explain why you consider inefficient to run some piece of code when you add an item?

Comment: @Steve He means that it's an annoying maintinance nightmare to have to call the method all over the code, instead of adding an event handler once.

Comment: Perhaps he could force a SelectedValueChanged when adding an element, but this is equally inefficient than calling a common method all over. A better way to go is to create a custom control that overrides the Add method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the logic in a separate class. That way you're only calling the one piece of code but you can also know when items are added.

There is no event for this that is native to the .NET listbox control. The only other option is subclassing the listbox and listening manually.

Comment: If this means what Steve said - making a new function - then I guess this will do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be easier in your case to Bind the `ListBox.Items` collection to an `ObservableCollection` so you can subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event?

Comment: Well, that would make it easier, but how?